# -ge: Unary Operator Expected

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

```
to_add=xyz.p@mail.com
alert=90
df -h |grep -e '/prod'| awk '{ print $5"used "$1}'| while read output;
do
usep=$(echo $output| awk '{ print $1}' | tr -d"%")
echo $usep
if [$usep -ge ${alert%} ]; then
echo "Alert: Used Percentage is:$usep"
df -h | mail -s "Alert: out of disk space $usep"  $to_add
fi
done
```

While running above shell script i am getting -ge : Unary operator expected

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the complete error message. Paste your script at `https://www.shellcheck.net/` and fix the errors. Maybe run your script with `bash -x your_script` to see what actually gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

> ```
> if [$usep -ge ${alert%} ]
>     ^
>     ^
> ```

Shells need to see a space on both inner ends of `[` `]`

Comment: Yes, neither `[` nor `]` is a metacharacter (in `bash` parlance), so it alone cannot separate words.

Comment: i have given space now after [ .. but still same error

Comment: There's a lot wrong with your original script and now we don't know what your updated version actually looks like. Do what [@Bodo's earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73109501/ge-unary-operator-expected#comment129122456_73109501) suggests then post a new question if you still have a problem.